# What will be the Time Complexity?

Tags: c++

What will be time complexity of this function if 'a' is vector of size n integers and assume 'i' to be 0?

```
    for (auto x : {a[i], a[n - i - 1]}) 
    {
            auto b = a;
            b.erase(std::remove(b.begin(), b.end(), x), b.end());
            auto c = b;
            std::reverse(c.begin(), c.end());
            
    }
```

Comment: `O(n)` if n > 0, otherwise undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity is linear, i.e. `O(n)`. Indeed, each of `b.erase()`, `std::remove()`, and `std::reverse()` have complexity `O(n)`, and the loop has 2 iterations (not affecting the complexity).

Comment: How the loop has 2 iteration?

Comment: `{a[i], a[n - i - 1]}` produces an initializer list of 2 elements.  `a[i]` and `a[n - i - 1]`.

Comment: ok ok now I got that thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is `O(n)`. All string functions in the loop are `O(n)` and the loop iterates twice, so we have 2*3n. Disregarding constants and lower order  terms, this becomes `O(n)`.